# Sequential Guid as string for Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure-storage

We would like to use sequential guids for our row keys in certain tables in Azure.

For Sql, I normally use a modified code snippet I found on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388157/GUIDs-as-fast-primary-keys-under-multiple-database).  It actually allows you to specify guid as a string, but it has checks on the BitConverters Endianess and i'm unsure if this will affect the ordering of the strings if they're made on different computers.  Can I ignore this and just write it a set way that will work with ATS?

The accuracy of the timestamp on it isn't that important, the ordering isn't critical at all, but being able to retrieve the creation time from just the guid is.

EDIT: added some results

```
public static class SequentialStringGuidGenerator
{
     public static Guid New()
     {
         byte[] uidBytes = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
         byte[] tickBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
         byte[] seqBytes = new byte[uidBytes.Length];

        // Mapping A
        seqBytes[0] = tickBytes[0];
        seqBytes[1] = tickBytes[1];
        seqBytes[2] = tickBytes[2];
        seqBytes[3] = tickBytes[3];
        seqBytes[4] = tickBytes[4];
        seqBytes[5] = tickBytes[5];
        seqBytes[6] = tickBytes[6];
        seqBytes[7] = tickBytes[7];

        // Mapping B
        seqBytes[0] = tickBytes[7];
        seqBytes[1] = tickBytes[6];
        seqBytes[2] = tickBytes[5];
        seqBytes[3] = tickBytes[4];
        seqBytes[4] = tickBytes[3];
        seqBytes[5] = tickBytes[2];
        seqBytes[6] = tickBytes[1];
        seqBytes[7] = tickBytes[0];

        // Mapping C
        // EDIT - this worked and was more random
        seqBytes[0] = tickBytes[2];
        seqBytes[1] = tickBytes[3];
        seqBytes[2] = tickBytes[4];
        seqBytes[3] = tickBytes[5];
        seqBytes[4] = tickBytes[6];
        seqBytes[5] = tickBytes[7];
        seqBytes[6] = tickBytes[1];
        seqBytes[7] = tickBytes[0];

        seqBytes[8] = uidBytes[0] ...etc

        return new Guid(seqBytes);
     }
}
```

I'm going to start testing different ways and see what 'seems' to work and then try and figure it out from there, but if anyone can add any critical insight that might bite me in the ass that would be great.

EDIT - small test

```
public class Testy : TableEntity
{
    public Testy()
    {

    }

    public Testy(int index)
    {
        PartitionKey = string.Empty;
        RowKey = GuidGenerator.CreateNew().ToString();
        Index = index;
    }

    public int Index { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tableClient = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("xxxx", "xxx"), true).CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("testing");
        table.CreateIfNotExists();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            var testy = new Testy(i);
            table.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(testy));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
   Mapping A - Examples
   e4af2bbc-e463-08d1-c642-fcca3a69fe4b 12/12/2014 20:48:09 0
   e4e1ae3d-e463-08d1-7d1d-d73a3f7c984c 12/12/2014 20:48:09 1
   e5000c27-e463-08d1-5109-07ab1b32af4c 12/12/2014 20:48:09 2
   e51e910f-e463-08d1-03d9-523a291a7145 12/12/2014 20:48:09 3
   e53d3d24-e463-08d1-576b-01703c80e743 12/12/2014 20:48:10 4
   e55b9b02-e463-08d1-87bb-3ff54d28a542 12/12/2014 20:48:10 5
   e57abc38-e463-08d1-5832-bc183d909144 12/12/2014 20:48:10 6
   e598f31a-e463*08d1-894f-6e45a31c374b 12/12/2014 20:48:10 7
   e5b702dd-e463-08d1-1f8b-6a04bed83b45 12/12/2014 20:48:10 8
   e5d62413-e463-08d1-b4e4-57653b770842 12/12/2014 20:48:11 9
   e5f481f5-e463-08d1-306c-da79a3170043 12/12/2014 20:48:11 10

   Mapping B - All out of order

   Mapping C
   e4650360-08d1-6fac-d1cd-865acca03746 12/12/2014 20:56:09 200
   e4650393-08d1-f055-ea2d-a2f0698d2f4e 12/12/2014 20:56:10 201
   e46503bf-08d1-a348-8baf-b6c826a5dc49 12/12/2014 20:56:10 202
   e46503dd-08d1-8ba6-8233-774c90578d46 12/12/2014 20:56:10 203
   e46503fe-08d1-93c3-acf2-4ab50d655c46 12/12/2014 20:56:10 204
   e465042a-08d1-0d41-8632-cbbf2a0f3140 12/12/2014 20:56:10 205
   e4650448-08d1-fe9e-356e-91a01885374c 12/12/2014 20:56:11 206
   e4650467-08d1-fb4a-5e8e-34c95cece845 12/12/2014 20:56:11 207
   e4650486-08d1-54ba-655e-02259e9b8e45 12/12/2014 20:56:11 208
   e46504a6-08d1-a202-e599-344c5351264b 12/12/2014 20:56:11 209
   e46504d1-08d1-4cf5-0437-cdce734bc741 12/12/2014 20:56:12 210
```

Looks like including tickBytes[6] and tickBytes[7] always produces the same code, which is undesireable, i'll exclude this and see if that helps.

Edit 2: Nvm that looks like the larger part of DateTime and of course that won't change over small time periods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update with the final - simple class, to generate and retrieve sequential guids in ATS

```
public static class AtsIdentityFactory
{
    public static Guid CreateSequentialId()
    {
        var uidBytes = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
        var tickBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
        var seqBytes = new byte[uidBytes.Length];

        seqBytes[0] = tickBytes[0];
        seqBytes[1] = tickBytes[1];
        seqBytes[2] = tickBytes[2];
        seqBytes[3] = tickBytes[3];
        seqBytes[4] = tickBytes[4];
        seqBytes[5] = tickBytes[5];
        seqBytes[6] = tickBytes[6];
        seqBytes[7] = tickBytes[7];
        seqBytes[8] = uidBytes[0];
        seqBytes[9] = uidBytes[1];
        seqBytes[10] = uidBytes[2];
        seqBytes[11] = uidBytes[3];
        seqBytes[12] = uidBytes[4];
        seqBytes[13] = uidBytes[5];
        seqBytes[14] = uidBytes[6];
        seqBytes[15] = uidBytes[7];

        return new Guid(seqBytes);
    }

    public static DateTime GetDateTime(Guid id)
    {
        var seqBytes = id.ToByteArray();
        var tickBytes = new byte[8];

        tickBytes[0] = seqBytes[0];
        tickBytes[1] = seqBytes[1];
        tickBytes[2] = seqBytes[2];
        tickBytes[3] = seqBytes[3];
        tickBytes[4] = seqBytes[4];
        tickBytes[5] = seqBytes[5];
        tickBytes[6] = seqBytes[6];
        tickBytes[7] = seqBytes[7];

        var ticks = BitConverter.ToInt64(tickBytes, 0);
        return new DateTime(ticks);
    }
}
```